# How to get high density bitmap from resource

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

According to [Google's iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html), I added my application icon (ic_launcher) in multiple densities. And it works correctly. But how can I programmatically get the icon in code?

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Usually I use this code, but I always decode an image of 64x64 dimension which none of my original icons has. How can I force the BitmapFactory to decode for instance XXXHPDI ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From api level 15 you can use following method [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawableForDensity%28int,%20int%29):

```
getResources().getDrawableForDensity(id, density);
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();// whichever you want to load
options.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM;
options.inTargetDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
options.inScaled = true;
```

Comment: Nope, this didn't work. The result was even more pixelated. Even when I changed inDensity with inTargetDensity, the result was not good.